# How to get clean top-corner dismiss button and format buttons in Android?

Tags: android

I have two questions.

1.) Right now I have a popup that has an X displaying inside on the top right, but I can't get it to appear overlaying the top right corner of the popup. What can I do to achieve the desired "X" button?

currently: https://i.stack.imgur.com/v6S7A.png

desired: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nwTXt.png

2.) My "Top Button" and "Bottom Button" fill the entire width of the screen even though I have it to wrap content. Is there a way to make the buttons be narrower? (Actually, I would like to have them both be narrower, but still the same width even if one button's text is longer than the other). Does it have something to do with the way I laid out the XML? Ideally, I want to have a background image on the popup, but when I put in the image, the image goes inside the 3 textviews too, which leads me to think that I don't have a very good XML file. Does anyone know how to solve this problem too? Thanks!

**layout/popup.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/dialog"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/popup_header"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:text="@string/popup_message"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textColor="#464646" >
</TextView>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/popup_text1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/popup_header"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
    android:text="@string/popup_message2"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:textColor="#464646" >
</TextView>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/popup_text2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/popup_text1"
    android:text="@string/popup_message3"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textColor="#464646" >
</TextView>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/top_button"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/popup_text2"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
    android:background="#f000ff"
    android:text="@string/top_button"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:textSize="20sp" >
</Button>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/bottom_button"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/top_button"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:background="#f000ff"
    android:text="@string/bottom_button"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:textSize="20sp" >
</Button>

<Button
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true" android:text="@string/dismiss"
    android:textColor="#FFF" android:background="@drawable/round_button_background"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
    android:layout_margin="5dp" android:layout_height="25dp"
    android:layout_width="25dp" android:textSize="12sp" android:textStyle="bold"
    android:onClick="cancelActivity" >
</Button>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**drawable/round_button_background.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:shape="oval">
    <solid android:color="#9F2200" />
    <stroke android:width="3dp" android:color="#FFF" />
</shape>
```

**values/styles.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <style name="Theme.CustomDialog"     parent="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:padding">4dp</item>
    <item name="android:background">#f8adfc</item>
  </style>
</resources>
```

Comment: You really shouldn't be adding X-dismiss buttons to Android Apps. Android has a well defined interface for dismissing dialogs and activities - the Back button. Don't try and change the behavior expected by users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// try this
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/dialog"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/popup_header"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:text="@string/popup_message"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textColor="#464646" >
        </TextView>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/popup_text1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/popup_header"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
            android:text="@string/popup_message2"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textColor="#464646" >
        </TextView>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/popup_text2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/popup_text1"
            android:text="@string/popup_message3"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textColor="#464646" >
        </TextView>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/top_button"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/popup_text2"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
            android:background="#f000ff"
            android:text="@string/top_button"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="20sp" >
        </Button>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/bottom_button"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/top_button"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:background="#f000ff"
            android:text="@string/bottom_button"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="20sp" />



    </RelativeLayout>
    <Button
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:background="@drawable/round_button_background"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:layout_width="25dp"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:onClick="cancelActivity"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution for the first question:

As you want to show the image in top left corner as suggested the link you provided
For this first you make an id for the root layout i.e Relativelayout as you declare dialog there,Now code like this

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/close"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/dialog"
        android:background="@drawable/close" />
```

As far the second question goes,i can see that the button you declared has a width match parent there.first make it wrap_contect for all the button. If this doesn't help you,give a static width for the popup in the java code itself dynamically